# How to change file download name in iframe?

Tags: html

My iframe tag look like bellow

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="'+file_url+'" frameBorder="0"> <p>Your browser does not support .</p></iframe>
```

file_url = store/ASDFVASDFADSFACASDFCDDF.doc

file_name = my word.doc

when i click on the iframe open link file download with incorrect file name.(doc file download with ASDFVASDFADSFACASDFCDDF.doc file name). how can i download file with real file name using iframe?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `iframe` element can't do that, but you could put this in a `.htaccess` file in the 'store' directory :

```
<FilesMatch ".doc$">
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=myword.doc"
</FilesMatch>
```

*Note that I'm assuming Apache here, but most webservers have a similar function*

Comment: But how we can pass dynamic filename. Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTML. You cannot do it.

The web server needs to send a "Content-Disposition" header. How to make your server do that depends what software is running on the server.

Alternatively... Just change the URL to this (and obviously move the file on the server):

store/ASDFVASDFADSFACASDFCDDF/Filename.doc

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers that support the `download` attribute, you should be able to specify in the following way:

```
<a href="http://google.com" download="awesome.html">Download</a>
```

The nice thing is, this will also trigger a forced download behavior in the browser.

Alternatively, you could pass your download through a PHP script to set the filename to be served in the headers, something like this:

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: `<iframe download>` doesn't seem to be a part of any spec I know of. Are you sure?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this `download` attribute from, but it's not listed in the W3C HTML5 specification under the [Global Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) section, the [`a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) section nor the [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) section.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought `download` probably doesn't work on the iframe, I'll update my comment to reflect that. You can read about the `download` attribute [here](http://developers.whatwg.org/links.html#downloading-resources)

Comment: @omgmog interesting. I guess they forgot to add it as an attribute on the `a` and `area` sections.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the attribute is by whatwg, which is a non-official group effort by several major browser vendors. They are not part of the official standards process, so often their wok doesn't become part of the standard.